# c appending data at two pointer address

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I have 2 functions that measure temperature and humidity. Each function returns a pointer to an address containing the data.

```
uint8_t * get_temperature(int *temperaturelen)
{
    memset(htpbuff, 0, sizeof(htpbuff));
    int temp_c = readTemperatureC();

    htpbuff[0] = 'T';
    htpbuff[1] = 'C';   
    htpbuff[2] = temp_c&0xff;
    htpbuff[3] = (temp_c>>8)&0xff;
    htpbuff[4] = (temp_c>>16)&0xff;
    htpbuff[5] = (temp_c>>24)&0xff;

    *temperaturelen = 6;  
    return (&htpbuff[0]);
} 

uint8_t * get_humidity(int *humiditylen)
{
    memset(htpbuff, 0, sizeof(htpbuff));
    int humidity = readHumidity();

    htpbuff[0] = 'R';
    htpbuff[1] = '%';
    htpbuff[2] = humidity&0xff;
    htpbuff[3] = (humidity>>8)&0xff;
    htpbuff[4] = (humidity>>16)&0xff;
    htpbuff[5] = (humidity>>24)&0xff;

    *humiditylen = 6;  
    return (&htpbuff[0]);
}
```

I call the functions like this:

```
tempptr = get_live_temperature(& temp_len);
humptr = get_live_humidity(& hum_len);
```

I want to appeand the data at each address into a single pointer so that the data at that address would look like `TC1234R%1234`.

How could I do this?

The reason why is I need to pass this new pointer to a function to transmit the data.

Thanks

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: Aren't you , like overwriting `htpbuff`?

Comment: Pass a pointer to a buffer allocated in the caller, simple as that.

Comment: @Lundin would you be able to demonstrate that?

Comment: Create an array, pass pointer to first element, write data there from function, pass pointer to _n_ th element to the next function, write data.